# Project property Settings is not a valid identifier

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, properties, settings, application-settings

I've been asked to make a few updates to an application that has not be changed in a few years. There are a lot of settings defined as part of the main project which can be viewed either in the app.config file or by viewing the project properties settings section.
I am trying to add a new setting value that is my machine name with these values:
Name 123_1111
Type string
Scope Application
Value TEST
but VS2012 generates this error "123_1111" is not a valid identifier.

How can I resolve this error to create this setting?

Comment: Can you put the actual code in your question? The app.config and the code using it preferably.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the name of the property can not contain only numbers. Try to rename your property to something like a123_1111